# Group_by_key in order in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, rdd

```
rrr = sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3])
fff = sc.parallelize([5, 6, 7, 8])
test = rrr.cartesian(fff)
```

Here's `test`:

```
[(1, 5),(1, 6),(1, 7),(1, 8),
 (2, 5),(2, 6),(2, 7),(2, 8),
 (3, 5),(3, 6),(3, 7),(3, 8)]
```

Is there a way to preserve the order after calling `groupByKey`:

```
test.groupByKey().mapValues(list).take(2)
```

Output is this where the list is in random order:
`Out[255]: [(1, [8, 5, 6, 7]), (2, [5, 8, 6, 7]), (3, [6, 8, 7, 5])]`

The desired output is:

```
[(1, [5,6,7,8]), (2, [5,6,7,8]), (3, [5,6,7,8])]
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add one more `mapValues` to sort the lists:

```
result = test.groupByKey().mapValues(list).mapValues(sorted)
```